# What does this keyword in the setOnClickListener refer to?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
```

What does `this` keyword in the `setOnClickListener(this)` function refer to?

Comment: Its `Context` of your activity class.

Answer (score 1):

It refers the interface that your activity implements, or should implement, otherwise an error is thrown of mismatching types.

In this case the interface should be a `View.OnClickListener`.